# Delay hover effect for child div

Tags: html, css, css-animations

In the attached snippet, when you hover on the parent `div`, the child `div` is shown. As expected, if you remove the cursor it then disappears.

Is it possible to delay this disappearance for like, 1 second somehow?

```css
ul {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
}

div {
  display: none;
}

ul:hover div {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Hover me</li>
  <div>
    Show on hover
  </div>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set transition speeds & delays without a CSS animation. The `transition-delay` effect doesn't apply to `display` properties on hover. It works best with `opacity: 0;` → `opacity: 1;` or `visibility: hidden;` → `visibility: visible;` See the changes I made to your CSS.

```css
ul {
  width: 100px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  background: red;
}

div {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .4s ease 3s;

}

ul:hover > div {
  background: red;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: .4s;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Hover me</li>
  <div>
    Show on hover
  </div>
</ul>
```

**EDIT:** Removed transition delay, and added transitions to both the `ul` and the `div` that has a starting opacity of 0. You can delay the mouse-out effect by adding `ease 3s` or however long you want the div to delay reverting to `opacity: 0;` when taking your mouse off.

Comment: Hey Kameron, you added the delay on the hover, where I believe the OP is asking for a delay on mouse-off.

Comment: That's right, thanks for the input anyway

Comment: @Smithy corrected, see edit.

Comment: Thanks, this looks nice, however the element shows even if I hover over the hidden element itself... unfortunately it does not work with the display property combined. Maybe I'll look into JS solution...

Comment: @Smithy Unfortunately, that is because the delays don't work great with using the display properties, and only elements that are still on the page but hidden (`opacity` , `visibility`) styles work best. Hence, causing you to hover over the hidden property to get it to display.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `transition:all .2s ease 2s;` attribute to delay the disappearing.

```css
ul {
  width: 100px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  background: red;
}

div {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .2s ease 2s;
}

ul:hover>div {
  background: red;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: .4s;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Hover me</li>
  <div>
    Show on hover
  </div>
</ul>
```